# How to grab the Optional response in swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I want to grab the ImagePath from the response.

Response look like this
[The response for print(response.result.value)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvfU7.png)

[image]

I am using Alamofire POST request to get the data from Api. Here is my code:

```
switch encodingResult {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                        if response.result.error != nil {

                        }
                        let Response = response.result.value
                        print("Response JSON:- \(String(describing: Response))")
                        let mydata = (String(describing : Response))
                        let jSon = JSON(mydata)
                        print("New :- \(String(describing: jSon["data"]["ImagePath"].stringValue))")
                        print("New :- \(jSon["data"]["ImagePath"])")
                        print(jSon["data"]["ImagePath"])
                        print(jSon["status"].stringValue)
                        if let data = response.result.value {
                            let json = JSON(data)

                            //print(json)
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: can you do `print(response.result.value)` , and add output to your question. BTW you are converting json data into string format and then parsing string just like json, thats never work.

Comment: The response for print(response.result.value) is :  Optional({
    data =     {
        ImagePath = "uploadfile/myImages.jpeg";
        ThumbImagePath = "uploadfile/thumb/myImages.jpeg";
    };
    status = 200;
    type = success;
})

Comment: Added as a image, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try optional handling this way

```
if let Response = response.result.value as? [String : Any],
       myData = Response["data"] as? [String : Any],
       imgPath = myData["ImagePath"]  {
       
       print("ImagePath --> ", imgPath)  
}
```

Comment: @Raonix Check now, you are new so make your habit to work like this. It  helps you alot in future my friend. More you work more you start gaining the knowledge on this, why how it works,, keeps your hands dirty